# Disable a field if another field is disabled

Tags: 8, forms

I need to disable field **A** if field **B** is disabled too.
Actually, my current field **A** has the following #states (altered using hook_alter_form) to disable it if field **B** or field **C** are empty:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
 
  $form['field_a']['#states'] = [
    'disabled' => [
      [':input[name="field_b[0][value][date]"]' => ['empty' => TRUE]],
      'or',
      [':input[name="field_c[0][value][date]"]' => ['empty' => TRUE]],
    ],
  ];
}
```

And it works perfectly, but I need to add the condition mentioned before.
I found this in the official documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/conditional-form-fields
and I tried to use some of them like 'readonly' or 'readwrite' but this didn't work.
Can I evaluate properties like '#disabled' from here? something similar to this:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['field_a']['#states'] = [
    'disabled' => [
      [':input[name="field_b[0][value][date]"]' => ['empty' => TRUE]],
      'or',
      [':input[name="field_c[0][value][date]"]' => ['empty' => TRUE]],
      'or',
      [':input[name="field_b"]' => ['#disabled' => TRUE]],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out the [Conditional Fields module](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields). It might cover your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with states here is what the docs says

> The following states may be used when checking values of other fields:
>
> ```
> empty
> filled
> checked
> unchecked
> expanded
> collapsed
> value
> ```

So, for this particular feature you will need to use some javascript or jquery.